# Accounts.resetPassword is undefined despite being documented thoroughly

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm debugging a Meteor method where, on my server, `Accounts` (imported as `import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';`) does not have a `resetPassword` value. It has such values as `.removeEmail`, `.createUser`, etc. but no `resetPassword`. I'm quite confused, as this is a pretty well documented method. I don't even see anyone having a similar problem on Google.

I'm on Meteor version 1.4.3.1 with accounts-password version 1.3.4.

Comment: change/forgot/reset password methods are only available on the client - see top right corner of the entry in the docs - http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-resetPassword

Comment: ah, thank you. Mind making an answer so I can mark you as correct?

Comment: Done! Added some detail as well to make it more worth a proper answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resetPassword`, `changePassword`, and `forgotPassword` methods are only available on the client. You can see this in the top right corner of the entry in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-resetPassword):

[image: changePassword screenshot from docs]

The server-side methods you might want to use are [sendResetPasswordEmail](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendResetPasswordEmail) or [setPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-setPassword)